# Integrating single variable out of marginal

Tags: probability, bayesian

I have just seen that

$$
P(w|x, y) = \int P(w|x, y, z) P(z|x, y) dz
$$

I thought it would be

$$
P(w|x, y) = P(x,y)\int P(w|x, y, z) P(z|x, y) dz
$$

Can someone explain to me why it isn't?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity we will denote
$$P(\cdot|x,y):=P(\cdot)$$
as the dependence is always present in the example.

Now, first think about it in terms of events. Let $C$ be the certain event, ie. $P(C)=1$. Than we have $W\cap C = W$. Than, let $C=\cup_i Z_i$, and $\cap_i Z_i = \emptyset$ (meaning that $Z_i$ are a perfect set of events).

$$P(W)=P(W\cap C)=P(W\cap\cup_i Z_i)=P(\cup_i W\cap E_i)=\sum_i P(W\cap Z_i)$$

which is the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). Now, in the continuous case

$$P(W\cap Z_i)=\int_{a_i}^{b_i} p(W|z)p(z)dz$$
Thus
$$P(W\cap Z)=\sum_i P(W\cap Z_i)=\int p(W|z)p(z)dz$$